# Workaround for deep linking using Xpath Links

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, hyperlink, bookmarklet

> Up until Firefox 5, Firefox supported XPath links such as #xpath:/html/body/div[3] which could be used in conjunction with a bookmarklet such as http://antimatter15.com/wp/2009/11/xpath-bookmark-bookmarklet/ to link within HTML documents that lacked proper IDs. This feature was removed as part of a code cleanup in https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=457102

I frequently want to reference to web pages that have good content but don't have proper IDs. So if a page is very long and I want to reference a specific part of it. I am unable to do it. Firefox had support of Xpath links but they have removed it now. Does anyone know how to overcome this problem

Comment: I am also looking for a workaround for such situations.

Comment: Would be great if this became an official standard for URLs across all browsers. Short of that I'm not sure how this could be done using a link alone.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use *XPaths* in [`document.evaluate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate)

```
// get node
var xpr = document.evaluate('/html/body/div[3]', document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null),
    elm = xpr.iterateNext();
```

Next, you can use [`elm.scrollIntoView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) (will not work in IE, see compatibility)

```
elm.scrollIntoView();
```